Useful usecase to use limitRate method from Reactor
reading the documentation of limitRate method from Reactor https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#limitRate-int- and testing with StepVerifier is not actually limiting the number of events flowing from upstream to downstream. As mentioned here https://inspired-it.nl/2022/03/21/how-does-limitrate-work-in-reactor/,  is about limiting the number of requests to upstream and to gain performance because we reduce the number of callings to the request method from Reactor. So:

Is there a usecase where this limitRate is useful?.


" StepVerifier is not actually limiting the number of events flowing from upstream to downstream" - can you share your code?

"is about limiting the number of requests to upstream and to gain performance because we reduce the number of callings to the request method from Reactor" - Is this not useful usecase for limit rate?

I dont mean that StepVerifier is the responsible for not limitating the flow of events, I mean this operator itself does not limit the events flowing from upstream to downstream. I understand that the act of asking for the Pusblisher to produce and emit events its an operation and takes x time and if you reduce the number of times you ask for the Publisher for it, less time your process will take but as I said, this operator does not have to do with the amount of events flowing at the same time in the pipeline. And the name of this method is very counterintuitive in my opinion.
